# problem using a custom 404 page in IIS

Tags: iis, http-status-code-404

I have a web site with a child directory set up as an application.  I set up the application to use a custom 404 page.  When I navigate to the url and put in a non existent page I get the following error message.  Any other asp page in the application works fine.  There isn't even any script in the 404 page... just plain html so I'm not sure what is causing this.  I've tried creating an application pool specifically for this application but that didn't help.  Thanks.

Error message: The specified request cannot be executed from current Application Pool

Comment: Try asking here: http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a registry key with the name IgnoreAppPoolForCustomErrors (type DWORD, value 1) in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Parameters\

See http://blogs.msdn.com/rakkimk/archive/2006/09/01/735684.aspx or http://www.yanghengfei.com/show-131-1.html for more information - seems to be a not so uncommon problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I added the key but it didn't help so I'm guessing I need to restart IIS.  Do you know if you have to reboot or restart IIS?  I haven't tried either because we have quite a few customers who would squak if I rebooted, cutting them off.

Comment: Restarting should be enough - maybe you could verify this in a testing environment to make sure that this actually solves your problem before shutting down a server "on duty"?